# Which one of the private set, working set and virtual memory has a higher impact on system performance?

Tags: memory, performance

Amongst an application private bytes, working set, and virtual memory, which one has the highest impact on system performance?
To be more clear, consider EsetNod32 antivirus.
If you look at `Task Manager` for example, to see how much memory it consumes during operation, you cant find any noticeable amount taking up memory.
But If you look at `Process Explorer`you can find detailed information on different sections.
Now my question is which of those criteria is responsible for an application execution (memory wise) impact on the system ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984186/what-is-private-bytes-virtual-bytes-working-set) , it's mentioned that "Private Bytes are a reasonable approximation of the amount of memory your executable is using".

This has the highest impact amongst the 3 on the performance of your process. The impact on your system (or OS since we're talking about processes here) has a lot to do with how much memory the user owned processes (I'm talking about processes that were started by you) are using.